# SQL where everything else

Tags: mysql, join

Consider two database tables, `Reports` and `Reports_has_properties`

```
Reports
------
id_report
1
2
3

Reports_has_properties
----------------------
id_report property
1         red
1         big
2         orange
3         blue
3         tiny
```

Problem: I only get only the reports with the property red, for example, but the query returns all the `id_report` that match with `id_report`

```
SELECT * FROM reports
INNER JOIN reports_has_properties
    ON reports_has_properties.id_report = reports.id_report
WHERE reports_has_properties.property = 'red'
```

**The logical explanion is:
IF reports_has_properties HAS AN id_report with another property, dont' select it!
The id_report 1 hast the property red and big, so isn't good.
But if I search for the property orange, the id_report 2 only have one property, so it's ok.**

I tried a lot of things but I have no more ideas. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The table Reports_has_properties has the property red and big for the id_report 1, so what I want is select only the rows with only the red property

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM reports
INNER JOIN reports_has_properties
    ON reports_has_properties.id_report = reports.id_report
WHERE reports_has_properties.property = 'red'
```

is the same as:

```
SELECT *
FROM reports
INNER JOIN reports_has_properties
    ON reports_has_properties.id_report = reports.id_report
    AND reports_has_properties.property = 'red'
```

which is not the same as

```
SELECT *
FROM reports
LEFT JOIN reports_has_properties
    ON reports_has_properties.id_report = reports.id_report
    AND reports_has_properties.property = 'red'
```

I'm not sure what results you are aiming for.

I think you might be aiming for:

```
SELECT *
FROM reports
INNER JOIN reports_has_properties
    ON reports_has_properties.id_report = reports.id_report
WHERE reports.id_report IN (
    SELECT reports_has_properties.id_report
    FROM reports_has_properties
    WHERE reports_has_properties.property = 'red'
)
```

i.e. get **ALL** the report properties for any reports that have the red property.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell the results that you're after.

If you want all the reds:

```
SELECT * FROM reports R
INNER JOIN reports_has_properties P
    ON P.id_report = R.id_report
WHERE P.property  = 'red';
```

If you want all the 3's:

```
SELECT * FROM reports R
INNER JOIN reports_has_properties P
    ON P.id_report = R.id_report
WHERE P.id_report = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not to clear what you are looking for ...

This query will return all reports with the "red" property and all other properties for that report_id.

```
SELECT R.*,P.property
  FROM reports R
     , reports_has_properties P
 WHERE R.id_report = P.id_report
   AND R.id_report in (select distinct id_report 
                         from reports_has_properties 
                        where property='red'
                      )
```